# Grid Scrollbar not working on I-pad

Tags: extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4.0.7

I have grid on my page. If there is too much data scrollbar automatically comes, in Chrome, Mozilla IE even on Safari as well.

But when I try to access the same application in I-pad , scroll bar are not working.

**Note**:- Grids reast fetures i.e. pagination etc are working fine. Only scrollbar are not working.

Is there any specific reason for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with Ext 4.0; it uses virtual scroller for grids and it's completely broken on touch devices. Ext JS 4.1 solves this problem and scrolling works on iPads, although scrollbars are not displayed.